# Bind List<object> to GridControl with custom columns

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, devexpress

I have such class

```
public class AuthorModel
{
    public int Id  { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

}
```

I have created GridControl in wpf devexpress, and set ItemsSource to List. (MyGrid.ItemsSource = myAuthorsList)
The question is: How to control column names, for example, I want grid control to show Your Name instead of Name as in a class?

I want to change column names after setting ItemsSource

Answer (score 0):

You can use several approaches to define column headers in DevExpress GridControl:

1. Define [columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl.Columns.property) in XAML and set the [Header](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.BaseColumn.Header.property) property:

```xml
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Id" Header="Author ID"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

2. Subscribe to the [GridControl.AutoGeneratedColumns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataControlBase.AutoGeneratedColumns.event) event, iterate through the GridControl.Columns collection and set column Headers in code.
3. Use [data annotation attributes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/8834/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Binding-to-Data/Applying-Data-Annotations) in your model and activate the [EnableSmartColumnsGeneration](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataControlBase.EnableSmartColumnsGeneration.property) option:

```cs
    public class AuthorModel
    {
        [Display(ShortName = "Author ID")]
        public int Id {
            get;
            set;
        }
        //...
    }
```

```xml
    <dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True">
        <!--...-->
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Note that you need to add a reference to the **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** assembly to use these attributes